# cannon.js rotated STATIC body no effect in physics domain

Tags: cannon.js, matrix-engine

I have wheel constructed from 18 rotated by 20 deg in circle.

Only initial position have physics other rotated object have no effect ?

I use STATIC but i rotate them all.

My object have overlaping in that case no physics,
if i have no overlaping STATIC object works even in active rotation.

Any suggestion ?

```js
   var tex = {
      source: ["res/images/wheel-roll/metal/1-low.png"],
      mix_operation: "multiply",
    };

    var tex2 = {
      source: ["res/images/bar.png"],
      mix_operation: "multiply",
    };

    var  GLOBAL_Z = -16.5

    var J = 0;
    for(var i = 0;i < 18;i++) {

      var b2 = new CANNON.Body({
        type: CANNON.Body.STATIC,
        mass: 0,
        linearDamping: 0.1,
        angularDamping: 0.5,
        position: new CANNON.Vec3(0, GLOBAL_Z, -1.6)
      });

      var b3 = new CANNON.Body({
        type: CANNON.Body.STATIC,
        mass: 0,
        linearDamping: 0.1,
        angularDamping: 0.5,
        position: new CANNON.Vec3(0, GLOBAL_Z, -1.7)
      });

      var texField = {
        source: ["res/images/wheel-roll/" + i + ".png"],
        mix_operation: "multiply",
      };

      matrixEngine.matrixWorld.world.Add("cubeLightTex", 0.2, "roll" + i, texField);
      if(i == 0) {
        matrixEngine.matrixWorld.world.Add("cubeLightTex", 0.1, "roll__" + i, tex2);
      } else {
        matrixEngine.matrixWorld.world.Add("cubeLightTex", 0.1, "roll__" + i, tex);
      }
      var locRot;
      var local = (i * 20) * Math.PI / 360;
      locRot = new CANNON.Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0);
      locRot.setFromAxisAngle(new CANNON.Vec3(0, 1, 0), local);
      var shape = new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(0.1, 3.1, 0.1))
      b2.addShape(shape, undefined, locRot)
      App.scene['roll__' + i].raycast.enabled = false;
      // App.scene['roll__' + i].geometry.setScaleByX(-0.1)
      // App.scene['roll__' + i].geometry.setScaleByY(-0.3)
      App.scene['roll__' + i].geometry.setScaleByZ(2.7)
      App.scene['roll__' + i].physics.currentBody = b2;
      App.scene['roll__' + i].physics.enabled = true;
      this.pWorld.world.addBody(b2);

      // NUMBERS FIELDS
      var locRotF;
      var localF = (i * 20 + 10) * Math.PI / 360;
      locRotF = new CANNON.Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0);
      locRotF.setFromAxisAngle(new CANNON.Vec3(0, 1, 0), localF);
      var shape = new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(0.2, 3, 0.1))
      b3.addShape(shape, undefined, locRotF)

      App.scene['roll' + i].raycast.enabled = false;
      // App.scene['roll' + i].geometry.setScaleByX(-0.1)

      App.scene['roll' + i].geometry.setScaleByY(-0.3)

      App.scene['roll' + i].geometry.setScaleByZ(2.6)
      App.scene['roll' + i].geometry.setTexCoordScaleXFactor(-1);
      App.scene['roll' + i].geometry.setTexCoordScaleYFactor(-5);

      App.scene['roll' + i].custom.gl_texture = function(object, t) {
        var world = matrixEngine.matrixWorld.world;
        world.GL.gl.bindTexture(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, object.textures[t]);
        world.GL.gl.texParameteri(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, world.GL.gl.LINEAR);
        world.GL.gl.texParameteri(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, world.GL.gl.LINEAR);
        world.GL.gl.texParameteri(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, world.GL.gl.REPEAT);
        world.GL.gl.texParameteri(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, world.GL.gl.REPEAT);
        world.GL.gl.texImage2D(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, world.GL.gl.RGB5_A1,
          world.GL.gl.RGB5_A1, world.GL.gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, object.textures[t].image)
      }

      App.scene['roll' + i].physics.currentBody = b3;
      App.scene['roll' + i].physics.enabled = true;

      setTimeout(function() {
        for(var i = 0;i < 18;i++) {
          App.scene['roll' + i].geometry.setTexCoordScaleXFactor(-1);
          App.scene['roll' + i].geometry.setTexCoordScaleYFactor(-5);
        }
      }, 500)

      this.pWorld.world.addBody(b3);

      // App.scene.ROLL_ROOT_NUM.subObjs.push(App.scene['roll' + i])
    }

  animateRoll() {

    var STEP = 0;
    this.rollTimer = setInterval(() => {
      for(var i = 0;i < 18;i++) {
        App.scene['roll' + i].rotation.roty =
          matrixEngine.utility.radToDeg(App.scene['roll' + i].physics.currentBody.quaternion.toAxisAngle()[1]);
        var locRot;
        if(STEP > 360) {
          STEP = 0
        }
        var N = (i * 20 + STEP) * Math.PI / 360;
        locRot = new CANNON.Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0);
        locRot.setFromAxisAngle(new CANNON.Vec3(0, 1, 0), N);

        App.scene['roll' + i].physics.currentBody.quaternion.copy(locRot)

        // numbers
        App.scene['roll__' + i].rotation.roty =
          matrixEngine.utility.radToDeg(App.scene['roll__' + i].physics.currentBody.quaternion.toAxisAngle()[1]);
        var locRot;
        if(STEP > 360) {
          STEP = 0
        }
        var N = (i * 20 + 10 + STEP) * Math.PI / 360;
        locRot = new CANNON.Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0);
        locRot.setFromAxisAngle(new CANNON.Vec3(0, 1, 0), N);
        App.scene['roll__' + i].physics.currentBody.quaternion.copy(locRot)
      }

      STEP = STEP + 1;

      this.C = this.C + this.speedRollInit
      if(this.speedRollInit < 0.02) {
        // clearInterval(this.rollTimer)
      } else {
        this.speedRollInit = this.speedRollInit - 0.0005
      }
    }, 12)
  }
```